# How to sort query results by distance in Laravel QueryBuilder / MySQL Spatial package?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

First I want to show you the current database structure. There are three tables:

**dishes** (id, name)

**locations** (id, name, coordinates (POINT))

**dish_location**(location_id, dish_id)

Now I want to implement an API which gets the position (latitude, longitude) of the user and returns a list of dishes sorted by the distance in km. I already have a method which takes two latitudes and two longitudes and gives me the distance. But I am sure you can show me a way, which is a more performant way to do this directly in the MySQL query.

**Additional:** I want to do a "load more"-function in the API. So I pass the count of already received items or how would I solve this in this case?

I am using this for the [MySQL Spatial package](https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial)

Comment: It's a two part sort.  You draw a square with the user's position at the center.  Then you subtract/add a max distance to search to get 4 minimum and maximum points.  Then you query the database to return results within that square.  Then you perform the real sort on this subset with the real formula, haversine I believe.

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that this is an unlimited list.

Comment: Then you have to find a way to limit the list...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's take a look at how to do this with the basic query builder. Then, we'll discuss how to execute this query with Eloquent models:

```php
function paginateDishesFromPoint(Point $point, $pageSize) 
{
    $distanceField = "ST_Distance_Sphere(locations.coordinates, "
        . "ST_GeomFromText('{$point->toWKT()}') AS distance"; 

    return DB::table('dishes') 
        ->select('dishes.*', DB::raw($distanceField))
        ->join('dish_locations', 'dish_locations.dish_id', '=', 'dishes.id')
        ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'dish_locations.location_id')
        ->orderBy('distance') 
        ->paginate($pageSize);
}
```

The `ST_Distance_Sphere()` function calculates a distance that we can sort results by. Laravel's `paginate()` method performs automatic pagination for us using the `page` parameter passed through the request URL. Read the [pagination docs](https://laravel.com/docs/pagination) for more information. With the function above, we can fetch a paginated result set as follows:

```
$point = new Point($latitude, $longitude); 
$sortedDishes = paginateDishesFromPoint($point, 15);
```

...where `Point` is the `Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point` class from [the package](https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial) we're using, and `15` is the number of results per page.

Now, let's try to do this with Eloquent models. We'll use a [local query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes) to encapsulate the logic needed to create the portion of the query that performs the ordering:

```
class Dish extends Model 
{
    ...

    public function locations() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Location::class);
    }

    public function scopeOrderByDistanceFrom($query, Point $point) 
    {
        $relation = $this->locations();
        $locationsTable = $relation->getRelated()->getTable();
        $distanceField = "ST_Distance_Sphere($locationsTable.coordinates, "
        . "ST_GeomFromText('{$point->toWKT()}') AS distance";

        return $query
            ->select($this->getTable() . '.*', DB::raw($distanceField))
            ->join(
                $relation->getTable(), 
                $relation->getQualifiedForeignKeyName(), 
                '=', 
                $relation->getQualifiedParentKeyName()
            )
            ->join(
                $locationsTable,
                $relation->getRelated()->getQualifiedKeyName(),
                '=', 
                $relation->getQualifiedRelatedKeyName()
            )
            ->orderBy('distance');
    }
}
```

This implementation uses metadata on the models to add the table and field names to the query so we don't need to update this method if they change. Now we can fetch the ordered set using the model:

```
$point = new Point($latitude, $longitude); 
$sortedDishes = Dish::orderByDistanceFrom($point)->paginate($pageSize);
```

`$sortedDishes` is an instance of Laravel's `LengthAwarePaginator` which wraps a `Collection` of the models. If we pass the results to a view, here's how to display them in a Blade template:

```html
<ul>
    @foreach($sortedDishes as $dish) 
        <li>{{ $dish->name }} is {{ $dish->distance }} meters away.</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

<a href="{{ $sortedDishes->nextPageUrl() }}">Load more...</a>
```

As shown above, the paginator provides [convenience methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#paginator-instance-methods) that we can use to easily move between paged results.

Alternatively, we could use AJAX requests to load the results. Just be sure to pass the *current page + 1* in the `page` parameter of the request data.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Do you have an idea, how I could get the location of the dish as field in the result array? In the model I have a function locations() for the locations relation but I only need the "one location" we are joining..

Comment: You're welcome! We could add `"$locationsTable.name AS location_name"` to the call to `select()` and this will be available as `$dish->location_name`. It seems strange to me that a "locations" is a many-to-many relationship with "dishes". Can a dish really exist in more than one location?

Answer (score 1):

**SQL**

```
SELECT d.name AS `Dish`,
       l.name AS `Location`,
       ST_Distance(l.coordinates, POINT(<<<longitude>>>, <<<latitude>>>)) AS `Distance`
FROM dish_locations dl
JOIN dishes d
ON d.id = dl.dish_id
JOIN locations l
ON l.id = dl.location_id
ORDER BY `Distance`
LIMIT <<<n-1>>>, <<<page size>>>;
```

...inserting `<<<longitude>>>` and `<<<latitude>>>` from the user's position, `<<<n-1>>>` from the number of rows that have already been retrieved minus one and `<<<page size>>>` as the desired next number of rows to retrieve.

**Demo**

http://rextester.com/YAEBF16430

**Explanation**

- [`ST_Distance_Sphere`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#idm139633850045360) is used to calculate the distance in meters.
- [`LIMIT <<offset>>, <<num>>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#idm139633840296464) is used to implement the paging (where offset is zero-based).

Comment: Thank you! The big question now is, if you know how to "convert" this pure SQL-query to Laravel code to build this query with the QueryBuilder ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries ). So I can profit of the auto-matching to my models and the loading of the relations.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Laravel but Cy Rossignol's answer seems to have addressed one way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Postgis has two operators (<-> and <#>) to work distance and calculate KNN(Nearest Neighbors). You can use them instead of st_distance. [Operators](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html)
Query would be something like:

```
WITH index_query AS (
 SELECT ST_Distance(geom, 'SRID=3005;POINT(1011102 450541)'::geometry) as d,edabbr, vaabbr
FROM va2005
ORDER BY geom <-> 'SRID=3005;POINT(1011102 450541)'::geometry LIMIT 100)
SELECT *
   FROM index_query
ORDER BY d limit 10;
```

Using distance as d you can order.