# Dynamic scope on related model and then sorting by distance

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, spatial-query

I have a table where I keep logs of locations of all users from where I need to grab the latest location of all the users and sort it by the distance from provided geometry point.

Locations table

| id | user_id | location | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | POINT | timestamp |
| 2 | 1 | POINT | timestamp |
| 3 | 2 | POINT | timestamp |
| 4 | 2 | POINT | timestamp |

The result should be

| id | user_id | location | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | POINT | timestamp |
| 4 | 2 | POINT | timestamp |

Then I need to sort users who are nearest to the provided point. I got how I can use MySQL Spatial function to get the distance but unable to sort with result above.
I refereed [this](https://nullthoughts.com/development/2019/10/08/dynamic-scope-on-latest-relationship-in-laravel/) for getting latest location and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531031/how-to-sort-query-results-by-distance-in-laravel-querybuilder-mysql-spatial-pa) from another stack-overflow answer but having hard time using both together.

I appreciate any help and thanks in advance

Comment: So show us what you got

Comment: Sorry I've got basically nothing. I made a scope but couldn't figure out how to proceed with it https://pastebin.com/DmQU76ps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT source_table.*, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY source_table.user_id 
                                        ORDER BY source_table.time DESC) rn
              FROM source_table )
SELECT cte.*
FROM cte
WHERE cte.rn = 1 
ORDER BY ST_Distance(cte.location, @specified_point)
```

Comment: Thank you sir for an answer. I need some time to process it by myself.